# KDE kwallet migrationsassistent

Tags: passwords, debian, kde-plasma

I'm using kwallet for a long time, but the migration assistent annoyes me. It's not new, but today i'm tiered of doing this over and over again. Everytime i log in to my debian system (with kde5), i have to enter at least:

1. the "migration assistant" asking for the wallet password
2. kwallet manager asking for the wallet's password
3. the "migration assistant" asking for my old wallet's password
4. kwallet manager asking for my old wallet's password
5. password for my gpg key

I hope i don't miss one.
How can i consolidate this to enter a password just once?

THX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From KDE4 to KDE5 the path to configuration files has changed from `$HOME/.kde` to `$HOME/.local`.
So the wallet migration assistant should have created a copy of your passwords in `$HOME/.local/share/kwalletd`. But as long as the old wallet exists at `$HOME/.kde4/share/apps/kwallet`, the migration assistant keeps checking.

Since I removed the wallet in KDE4 configuration, the migration assistant keeps quiet.

Before removing the old wallet, I would

- check that a wallet in the KDE5 configuration exists
- export both wallets and compare the content
- make sure to have a **backup** of the wallets

Comment: That helped! I renamed $HOME/.local/share/kwalletd/ -> signed off -> signed on -> bingo, no more "migration assistant", no more PWD for my old wallet

Comment: KDE Devs should test their code before announcing 'everything works automatically'. Every PC I have, had problems with that upgrade. Removing the old kde4 files solved the problem for the last PC. Thx